# High CPU usage in Socket IO

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, socket.io, cpu-usage, server-configuration

I have a VPS with the following configuration:

Processor: 8 cores 2.8 GHz

Memory: 8 GB

Disk: 40 GB SSD

Operating system: Ubuntu 20

This is for a chat application implemented in NodeJS using Socket IO and Express. MongoDB database is used and Redis is used for `@socket.io/redis-adapter` (sharded adapter).

When about **700** clients are connected to the server and are sending messages and calling REST APIs, the average server load is 15 (which is given in the screenshot), while less than 4 GB of memory is used and the application slows down.
(When I used 6 processor cores, 7 GB of memory was used)

My question is: Is this amount of CPU usage normal for this number of clients? Or is my server not well implemented?

Now, should I upgrade the server or redeploy the application?

[image: htop screenshot]

**Update:** In a real test, I generated output from a Node JS app using `node --prof`. [This output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fmx2exOtlCadgfvPvmmOcReKFCc_lVxW/view) is related to one of the server application workers.

Comment: To begin with, you should run a profiler to figure out what your application is spending its time on.

Comment: @AKX I made an output using `node --prof` and updated the question. But I don't know how to interpret this output.

Comment: Great! Was that from the app as it is running in production, or something else? Either way, it looks like it's spending a lot of its time (and by extension, CPU cycles) talking to MongoDB.

Comment: Yes, it was in production mode. I have not used complex queries in MongoDB. Therefore, it can be concluded that there is no problem in the implementation?

Comment: No, it can't. For instance, if your app is doing extra MongoDB queries for each message that would really only need to be done once on app startup, I'd say that was a problem in the implementation.